# Как выполнить цикл с асинхронными вызовами синхронно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Умею строить цепочку Promis-ов. Но этот метод не подходит, так обработать в цикле нужно больше 5 миллионов строк(по другому больше 5 миллионов циклов).

Пример:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000 i++) {
    //Вместо http.get может быть любая другая, привел для примера
    http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
    // Обработка результата
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно на эвентах сделать, конечно код будет заметно больше, но зато более контролируемый.

Comment: @vnn198 Да, я думаю это самое то будет. В итоге я смог написать и синхронный и асинхронный код. Отличие колоссальное и не блокирующий I/O дает свои результаты. К примеру синхронный 19 минут, а асинхронный (с контролем количества не завершенных вызовов ) примерно 10 секунд (1000 запросов). Тут нужно сделать примечание, что в коде практически не было обработки полученной информации. Но все равно результат впечатлило.

Так как я в JS новичок и пока только книжку прочитать успел, то может покажете пример на эвентах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var urls = [
  "//ru.stackoverflow.com/",
  "//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/",
  "//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619018/178988"
];

(function go(i) {
  if (i < urls.length) {
    fetch(urls[i], {mode:'no-cors'}).then(function () {
      console.log(urls[i]);
      go(i+1);
    })
  }
})(0);
```

Comment: Есть большие сомнения, что нода справится с рекурсией глубиной в 5 млн. Во всяком случае, у меня сейчас при проверке упала в районе 17000 с ошибкой "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: @Yaant, операция асинхронная - она не попадает в стек в рекурсивном варианте - она должна быть в начале. Можно пример кода, который не работает?

Comment: Ну, я тупо сделал рекурсию на 5 миллионов, без дополнительных вызовов: `function f(n) {if (n == 5000000) return 'done'; f(n+1); }; f(1)`;

Comment: @Yaant, не, так не надо. Хотя, ES6 вводит оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии, которая в node 8 уже должна работать. Добавь хотя бы setTimeout - тогда переполнения стека быть не должно. Только 5000 секунд - это около полутора часов))

Comment: Да, с `setTimeout(f, 1, n+t)` всё работает, возражение снимается :)

Comment: @Yaant, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/619130/178988

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52432/discussion-between-yaant-and-qwertiy).

Comment: @Yaant Я как сделал: контроль загруженности стека. При 800 работал нормально, при 1000 уже были проблемы. Количество незавершенных операций должно быть контролируемым, так как иначе он съест память. 

Поправьте, если я что-то не правильно понимаю.

Comment: @Sergey, что-то неправильно, потому что стек пустой.