# Рекурсивно отправить GET запрос. Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Отправляю GET запрос, получаю данные. Эти данные все время обновляются ( спустя пару минут ). Нужно при первом GET запросе получить данные с нескольких следующих страниц.
Пример для более правильного объяснения ( скриншот - данные в формате json, прошу обратить внимание на `next_page`:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После каждого получения данных я сохраняю их в свою БД. По сути, мне необходимо сделать синхронизацию с центральной базой данных.
Подскажите, реально ли такое реализовать? Я так понимаю, что необходимо рекурсивно слать запрос до момента, пока next_page не будет. После этого подождать какое-то время ( `setInterval` ) и снова отправлять запросы на изменение данных в ЦБД.

На данный момент мой get request имеет такой вид ( код сохранения в БД добавлять пока не буду ).

```
let url = `http://publiement.org/api/2.4/trs?offset=${new Date().toISOString()}+02.00`;
function getData() {
  request(url, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    url = `http://publicurent.org/api/2.4/ts?offset=${body.next_item}`;
    saveDataToDb(body);
  });
}
```

Пользуясь таким способам, я теряю данные и опаздываю за обновлениями центральной базы данных. Не могли бы помочь с тем, как это дело реализовать

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, и вам нужно постоянно поддерживать клиентов в актуальном состоянии, то вам стоит почитать про [Long Pulling](http://javascript.ru/ajax/comet/long-poll) или [реактивные приложения](https://habrahabr.ru/post/279715/)

Comment: @vihtor да, но это не совсем лонг поллинг. Вопрос в том, как догнать с моего начального состояния текущее состояние Центральной базы данных..

Comment: вы имеете в виду как объединить текущие данные с вновь пришедшими?

Comment: нет, это понятно, в БД этим займется update с upsert: true; смотрите, я начинаю слать запрос например в 11.00 по своему времени, а в бд в это время уже есть данные и на 11.02, 11.04, 11.06. путь на эти страницы находится в next_page, как я описывал в вопросе. вот мне нужно в начале, при первом своем запросе собрать данные со всех существующих next_page.

Comment: я думал, что у меня нечтно похожее с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619018/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не совсем понимаю как это реализовать..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так

```js
function updateData(url) {
  return request(url, { json: true }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    saveDataToDb(body);
    console.log(`Send data to save`);

    if (body.next_page) {
      updateData(body.next_page.uri);
      console.log(`I requested the next page`);
    } else {
      console.log(`I done`);
    }
  });
}

updateData(uri);
```